# Identify which nested property is null in model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public class Book
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }        
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public  Author Author { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public  Category Category { get; set; }
     }
```

Query to the database over eager loading returns model null if  one of its included nested classes is null. I have a book entity that has two subordinate classes - **Author** and **Category**. I want to identify the nested entity which is null and exclude it from the query. If both of them are null then exclude them both and return only Book by given id. I wrote out the following lambda queries but it looks a bit rough, too many times hit to the database and needs to get simplified. Is there a better way to make this logic look more elegant and simplified?

```
public ActionResult ProductView (int? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        var book = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == id).Include(b => b.Author).Include(b=> b.Category.Books).SingleOrDefault();
        if(book==null)
        {
            var bookWithCtg = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == id).Include(b => b.Category).SingleOrDefault();
            var bookWithAuth = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == id).Include(b => b.Author).SingleOrDefault();

            if (bookWithCtg == null&& bookWithAuth ==null)
                book = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

            else if(bookWithAuth==null)
                book = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == id).Include(b => b.Category.Books).SingleOrDefault();

            else if (bookWithCtg == null)
                book = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == id).Include(b => b.Author).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        book.DisplayNumber++;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(book);
    }

    else
       return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Comment: Is this code first? If your navigation properties are set in the table definition then `Author` and `Category` should be included anyway. You could also check to see if the book exists.

Comment: @PeterSmith yes code first. But if one subclass in the model is null then the `var book` equals to `null` if I use eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your navigation property configuration, EntityFramework uses **inner join** when joining books, author and category. 
If author and category of a book **can be null**, you have to define AuthorId and CategoryId as **nullable int**, and also change your entity type configuration as following:

```
HasOptional(b => b.Author)
 .WithMany(a => a.Books)
 .HasForeignKey(b => b.AuthorId)

HasOptional(b => b.Category)
 .WithMany(a => a.Books)
 .HasForeignKey(b => b.CategoryId)
```

After this configuration you can simply include Author and Category.

```
var book = db.Books
 .Where(b => b.Id == id)
 .Include(b => b.Author)
 .Include(b=> b.Category)
 .SingleOrDefault();
```

Now, this query will return a book data regardless of Author and Category.

Comment: I have to do this configuration inside DataContext class OnModelCreating method?

Comment: @Cavid, where are your other configurations?

Comment: configurations for entites in the context class derived from DbContext class.

Comment: @Cavid, above configurations must be at the same place as your current configurations

Comment: I got this confiction after these configurations `Book_Author: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Book_Author_Target' in relationship 'Book_Author'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
AuthorTest.Entities.Book_Category: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Book_Category_Target' in relationship 'Book_Category'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'`

Comment: @Cavid, did you change the type of AuthorId and CategoryId of Book entity to Nullable<int> ?

Comment: yes I made CategoryId and AuthorId nullable in the property definition and also in the database they are allowed to accept null but now I got following error : `The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Books_dbo.Categories_CategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "NewBookStore", table "dbo.Categories", column 'Id'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195858/discussion-between-cavid-and-natiq).